# .htaccess redirect to subdirectory without changing url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I have the site

www.site.com

I would like the root directory to read from the /en subdirectory

WITHOUT changing the url to

www.site.com/en on the address bar

Answer (score 1):

Putting this in the .htaccess file in your root directory should do the trick, assuming of course mod_rewrite is installed and enabled, and AllowOverride All is set in the VirtualHost of the conf file. It won't change the address bar.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ en/$1 [L, NC, QSA]
```

Comment: how the htaccess could determine the language and redirects to the good one? French by example: www.site.com/fr.

Comment: Try this condition: `RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]` `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ fr/$1

Comment: This does not work in Apache 2.4 on shared hosting, maybe there is some apache-conf directive that prohibits this?